# Why do simultaneous Google web app users contaminate results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-app-maker

I wrote my first web app using Google App Maker, which edits a spreadsheet file to create a report customized for the user, and allows the user to download a copy of the report.  The program is really simple, it just:

1. enters the user's user account name into a certain cell of the Sheets document,
2. flushes the spreadsheet (which dynamically updates it according to the user account name),
3. creates a PDF of the updated spreadsheet - which is a test score report,
4. and allows the user to download a pdf of their report.

It all works fine, except when several students run the web app simultaneously.  If that happens, some of the students end up with another student's report.

My understanding was that changes made to a Google Sheets document by the server script in my web app would not be saved to the document unless I saved them intentionally.  So my hope was that simultaneous users would not have any impact on each other.

I'm really stuck as to how to resolve this issue.  Here's my code:

App startup script (runs as soon as the app is loaded):

```
downloadReport();
```

Client script

```
function showDownloadLink(downloadURL){
  console.log(downloadURL);
  var spinnerWidgets = app.pages.appPage.descendants.progressSpinner;
  spinnerWidgets.visible = false;
  var linkWidgets = app.pages.appPage.descendants.downloadPDFLink;
  linkWidgets.href = downloadURL;
  linkWidgets.visible = true;
}

function downloadReport() {
  var status = app.pages.appPage.descendants.downloadStatus;
  var user = app.user.username;
  var downloadLink = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showDownloadLink)
  .createDownload(user);
}
```

Server script:

```
// Spreadsheet file must have a tab called Report

function createDownload(user) {
///*
// SET SPREADSHEET FILE ID 
  var ssID = 'xxxxxxxxx_SHEETS_FILE_ID_GOES_HERE_xxxxxxxxxx';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
// determines timezone
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
// gets the destination folder using spreadsheet location (folder)
  var ssFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID).getParents();     
  var folder = ssFolder.next();
  var folderId = folder.getId();
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
//  Logger.log('destination name: ' + destination.getName());

// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone , "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

// gets the name of the original file and appends the ID and the timestamp stored in formattedDate
    var PDFfileName = ss.getName()+formattedDate+ "-" + user;

// inputs ID into daughter spreadsheet reference cell to personalize report
    ss.getSheetByName("Report").getRange(3, 1).setValue(user);      // Puts ID into cell A3
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();                                         // Updates the spreadsheet with changes and refreshes report

// Export URL
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ssID);

 var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'     // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                               // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=true'                             // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&top_margin=0.30'                           // sets top margin of pdf file  
  + '&bottom_margin=0.28'                        // sets bottom margin of pdf file
  + '&left_margin=0.43'                          // sets left margin of pdf file
  + '&right_margin=0.43'                         // sets right margin of pdf file
  + '&fitw=true'                                 // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'         // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'         // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                                 // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                                     // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

// Take snapshot and save to PDF
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    var blob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(PDFfileName + '.pdf'); 
    var newPDFFile = folder.createFile(blob);
    newPDFFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

// Link URL
    var downloadURL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+newPDFFile.getId();

    return downloadURL;
}
```

Comment: Just by looking at your code real quick I'd say your problem is here ss.getSheetByName("Report").getRange(3, 1).setValue(user); At least initially it appears that you overwrite the same cell value with each user submission, therefore, before you call your UrlFetchApp your cell value may have already been changed because of a concurrent user session. You would be better off creating a new spreadsheet with each submission, converting it to PDF and then using the Drive API to delete the created spreadsheet. In that case you could set up a template and make a copy instead and replacing cell values

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Markus!  I originally tried that, but ran into an issue as my Sheet file does use importrange() which requires permission to access the referenced Sheet when a copy of the file is created.  Therefore, the copy would not dynamically update when the user account is added to cell A3 of the Report  tab (sheet).  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Presumably your application is probably set to run as user. The only thing I could possibly suggest in that case is to set the template sharing settings to 'view - everyone with the link' because in that case it will pull the file from the developer account, but make the copy in the user account. I suppose you might be able to use team drives in this case as well, but you would need to play with the permission settings.

Comment: I have the app set to run as developers account - and it is shared with anyone in my domain group with the link. It is curious to me, because the Sheets file is not changed permanently by users that run the app - in other words their username is not left in the Sheets document after the script runs.  It's puzzling.

Comment: I would consider using LockService on createDownload so only one user can use it at a time.